# Can't put Future in Manager().Queue in Python

Tags: python, queue, python-multiprocessing

I have a bunch of client processes which make queries to a single worker process (which then processes them in batches) using a shared queue. However the clients need to know when the results are ready, so I tried putting a tuple with a concurrent.futures.Future along with the request in the queue, but Python throws a "cannot pickle" exception (this only happens with the future object).

Is there a picklable version of Future that I can use for this purpose, or a better design altogether?

Comment: result queues..?

Comment: @thebjorn you mean a queue going back in the other direction? But then for each request to get its own result wouldn't I have to make a new Manager().Queue for each request and put it in place of the Future?

Comment: @thebjorn I sort of see what you're saying but I don't know how to make it work with batch processing...