# Inverse of ProcessPoolExecutor in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This is related to my [earlier problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47890254/cant-put-future-in-manager-queue-in-python) which I'm still working on solving. Essentially I need the inverse design of ProcessPoolExecutor, where I have many querying processes and one worker which calculates and sends back results in batches.

Sending the work items is easy with one shared queue, but I still don't have a nice solution for sending all the results back to the right threads on the right processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it makes the most sense to have a separate `multiprocessing.pipe` for each querying process. The worker process waits for an available item on any pipe, and the dequeues and processes it, keeping track of which pipe it came from. When it's time to send data back, it feeds the results onto the correct pipe.

Here's a simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(pipes):
    quit = [False] * len(pipes)
    results = [''] * len(pipes)

    # Wait for all workers to send None before quitting
    while not all(quit):
        ready = mp.connection.wait(pipes)
        for pipe in ready:

            # Get index of query proc's pipe
            i = pipes.index(pipe)

            # Receive and "process"
            obj = pipe.recv()
            if obj is None:
                quit[i] = True
                continue
            result = str(obj)
            results[i] += result

            # Send back to query proc
            pipes[i].send(result)
    print(results)


def query(pipe):
    for i in 'do some work':
        pipe.send(i)
        assert pipe.recv() == i
    pipe.send(None) # Send sentinel

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nquery_procs = 8
    work_pipes, query_pipes = zip(*(mp.Pipe() for _ in range(nquery_procs)))

    query_procs = [mp.Process(target=query, args=(pipe,)) for pipe in query_pipes]
    for p in query_procs:
        p.start()
    worker(work_pipes)
    for p in query_procs:
        p.join()
```

Alternatively, you could give each querying process an ID number (which might just be its pipe's index), and any request must be a tuple which is `(id_num, data)`. This just gets around the worker process doing `pipes.index(pipe)` on each loop, so I'm not sure how much it buys you.

Comment: Thanks! I actually have a threadpool on each process so I think I'd have to make a pipe for each thread. Is there a significant overhead to just making a new Pipe() for every request (several hundred/sec) and just sending that in the request pipe? Or would it have to be a Manager().Queue() to be picklable? In which case, what does it even mean to say that multiprocessing.Queue is process-safe...

Comment: @Akababa You'd have to profile to be sure, but I'd bet that creating a new pipe for each request is expensive. Especially if each thread makes multiple requests, I would create them all at the beginning.

Comment: Quick follow up: I got it working using a pool of shared queues, popping one and putting it into the work item. Since the "pickling" involves only a pointer to shared memory, this should be efficient, right?

Comment: @Akababa If I understand your comment, you mean that you have a pool of queues; a query proc takes one and sends it along with data to be processed; the worker processes and sends result back on the queue; the query proc puts it back in the pool. If that's right, it should be fine, but whether or not the data is transferred via shared memory depends on what IPC mechanism you're using. If it's `multiprocessing.Pipe` objects, then, no, it's sent over OS pipes or sockets, not in shared memory. Pickling packs/unpacks the object to bytes to be sent over this pipe.